# Can't find "Set as Django Project" or Django actions in Eclipse with Pydev

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev, aptana3

MacOSX10.9.5, EclipseMars.1(4.5.1), Pydev3.0.0, Python3.4.3, Django1.9

I can't find "Set as Django Project" or Django actions in Eclipse though I could use it until yesterday.

[image]

I reinstalled the same versions of Python, Django, Eclipse and AptanaStudio3, and added Python and Django PATH to PYTHONPATH of Pydev Python Interpreter in Preferences again but the problem is not solved. I can't also create a new Pydev project. Maybe I deleted some important dotfile by mistake when I emptied the trash but I'm not sure if I did or if it's the cause or not. How can I fix the problem or what should I check to figure out what is the cause? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by myself. I just didn't notice the Pydev perspective was closed.

Window --> Perspective --> Open Perspective --> Other... and choose Pydev.

That's all. Now I can see Set as Django and Django actions with the Django logo. I had overlooked such a basic. Thank you!